# Subsonic map POCO to table of a different name

Tags: subsonic, mapping, subsonic3, poco, simplerepository

I started a small project and wanted to use Subsonic's SimpleRepository for my database layer.     If I have table in my database called Member and I want to create a POCO called TeamMember. Can I map class TeamMember to table Member via an attribute or some other method? It is possible that what I'm asking is not how the SimpleRepository objects are supposed to be used and if this is the case I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you,
- e r i c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can - but I might suggest using Inheritance instead. Remember - SimpleRepo is model-->DB, not the other way round.